# SQL to split mutilple row by date

Tags: sql-server

Let's say I have these values in a table

```
| Start Date              | End date                   |Other Value
---------------------------------------------------------------------
| 2015-01-07 01:00:00.000 | 2015-01-08 04:00:00.000    | Yes
| 2015-01-08 10:00:00.000 | 2015-01-10 20:00:00.000    | No
```

I want to write a select statement that should give me results like:

```
|Date        | Start Date   | End date     |Other Value
-----------------------------------------------------------
|2015-01-07  | 01:00:00.000 |              | Yes
|2015-01-08  |              | 04:00:00.000 | Yes
|2015-01-08  | 10:00:00.000 |              | No
|2015-01-10  |              | 20:00:00.000 | No
```

Is there a way to do it in T-SQL?

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this..

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3393e/1)

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn,startdate,enddate, othervalue  FROM yourtable
)
,cte1 AS
(
SELECT rn,cast(startdate AS DATE) AS [date]
         ,CAST(startdate AS TIME) AS [Start Date]
         ,null AS [End date]
         , othervalue 
FROM cte
UNION all
SELECT rn,cast(Enddate AS DATE) AS [date]
          ,null AS [Start Date]
          ,CAST(Enddate AS TIME) AS [End date], 
          othervalue 
FROM cte
)

sELECT * FROM CTE1 ORDER BY RN,[Start Date] desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION ALL and ROW_NUMBER() to order your result, like this:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
   SELECT *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) AS rownum
   FROM Your_Table
)
SELECT
   rownum,
   CAST([Start date] AS DATE) AS [Date],
   CAST([Start date] AS DATE) AS [Start date],
   NULL AS [End date],
   [Other Value]
FROM CTE

UNION ALL

SELECT
   rownum,
   CAST([End date] AS DATE) AS [Date],
   NULL AS [Start date],
   CAST([End date] AS DATE) AS [End date],       
   [Other Value]
FROM CTE

ORDER BY rownum
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `CROSS APPLY` and `VALUES`:

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0a6eb/1/0)

```
SELECT
    x.*, t.OtherValue
FROM tbl t
CROSS APPLY(VALUES
    (CAST(StartDate AS DATE), CAST(StartDate AS TIME), NULL),
    (CAST(EndDate AS DATE), NULL, CAST(EndDate  AS TIME))
)x(Date, StartDate, EndDate)
```

**This method scans the table only once.**